# How do I alter what I spool based on a condition?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I always want to spool, but the actual contents of the spool should be conditional. Here is a bit of pseudocode to explain what I need:

```
DECLARE
    vCondition VARCHAR2(5) := NULL;
BEGIN
    SELECT Field INTO vCondition FROM Table
    IF (vCondition = 'True') THEN
      spool C:\Location
        'Error'
      spool OFF;
    ELSE
      spool C:\Location
        'Success'
      spool OFF;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

--- EDIT ---

I've followed your first suggestion but I have run into another problem as a result of not elaborating enough in my pseudocode. I need to spool the result of a SELECT statement. Do you see any issue with this code?

```
spool C:\Location
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
    vCondition VARCHAR2(5) := NULL;
BEGIN
    SELECT Field INTO vCondition FROM Table;
    IF (vCondition = 'True') THEN
      SELECT Field_A || ',' ||
             Field_B || ',' ||
             Field_C || ',' ||
      FROM Table;
    ELSE
      SELECT Field_X || ',' ||
             Field_Y || ',' ||
             Field_Z || ',' ||
      FROM Table;
    END IF;
END;
/

spool OFF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control spooling from inside a PL/SQL block; it's a client function, not a server function, and the PL/SQL executes on the server. You need to start/stop spooling outside your anonymous block, and then have your block generate output which the spooling captures.

Assuming you want to spool to a file on the client machine you can do:

```
spool C:\Location
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
    vCondition VARCHAR2(5) := NULL;
BEGIN
    SELECT Field INTO vCondition FROM YourTable
    IF (vCondition = 'True') THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Error');
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('Success');
    END IF;
END;
/

spool OFF;
```

You shouldn't assume that `dbms_output` will be enabled unless you control the execution of the block. It's useful for debugging and will be OK here. But if you had a `dbms_output` call in a procedure then you wouldn't know that everyone that called it would be able to see the output.

In your simple example you could also skip the PL/SQL block completely and use a case expression, assuming you're only looking at a single table:

```
spool C:\Location
set heading off

SELECT CASE WHEN Field = 'True' THEN 'Error' ELSE 'Success' END
FROM YourTable;

spool OFF;
```

... but I imagine your real code is more complicated and does need to use PL/SQL.

If you want the file to be on the server you can use the `utl_file` package instead of spooling.

---

Based on your updated question, if all the queries are against the same table you can do:

```
spool C:\Location
set heading off

SELECT CASE WHEN Field = 'True' THEN Field_A ELSE Field_X END ||','||
       CASE WHEN Field = 'True' THEN Field_B ELSE Field_Y END ||','||
       CASE WHEN Field = 'True' THEN Field_C ELSE Field_Z END
FROM YourTable;

spool OFF;
```

Comment: I edited my question and I'm not sure if it notified you. Do you see anything wrong with this revision of the pseudocode?

Comment: @Jake - no, you don't get notifications for question edits (or answer edits, as far as I know). That isn't valid PL/SQL, you have to select into something. Do you really need to use PL/SQL? Are all three selects (to get vCondition and A/B/C and X/Y/Z) all from the same table?